# Search and replace: Replace substring of match (with substitute(...))

Tags: substitute

I have a C program where I have to change a 2D array into a 1D array.

What I want is to change this code:

```
temp[i][j] = (Grid[i][j-1] + Grid[i][j] + Grid[i+1][j] + Grid[i][j+1])/5
```

to this one:

```
temp[i*PPE+j] = (Grid[i*PPE+j-1] + Grid[i*PPE+j] + Grid[(i+1)*PPE+j] + Grid[i*PPE+j+1])/5
```

Because I'm new to Vimscript I split the problem into two parts and tried to tackle the first one:

- `[i][j]` -> `[i*PPE+j]`
- `[i+1][j+1]` -> `[(i+1)*PPE+j+1]`

I tried the following until now:

```
:%s#\v[^0-9](\]\[)[a-z][^-+]#\=substitute("\1","*PPE+", "", "")#gc
```

My reasoning behind this:

- `:%s#\v`:  go through whole file and use magic
- `[^0-9](\]\[)[a-z][^-+]`: match `<nonumber>][<char><not+or->` and () for establishing a group
- `\=substitute("\1","*PPE+", "", "")`: substitute the first group ( `][` ) with *PPE+
- `gc`: `g` for all matches in one line and `c` for confirmation query

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work as it replaces `i][j]` with `^A`

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I did not try it. But one thing I noticed immediately is that you cannot use so called `sub-replace-specials` ie. `\1` after `\=`. This should be `submatch(1)`. This is mentioned under [`:h sub-replace-expression`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#sub-replace-expression).

Comment: I tried this too but then it replaces `[i][j]`with `[][`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

Again, I'm not sure if I fully understand your goal, but the following two commands convert your "before" into your "after":

Handle the `i+1` case:

```
:%s/\v(\D[+-]\d)\]\[/(\1)*PPE+
```

Do all the rest:

```
:%s/]\[/*PPE+/g
```

The first command replaces:

```
<not-a-digit><plus-or-minus><digit>][
```

with:

```
(<captured-group>)*PPE+
```

The second command simply replaces all remaining instances of `][` with `*PPE+`.

**Original Answer regarding `[i][j]` only**

If I understand your question rightly, I'm not sure if using a [sub-replace-expression](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#sub-replace-expression) is the best tool for this job. Perhaps [`\zs`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Czs) and [`\ze`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Cze) are better suited to the task?

Try this command:

```
:%s/\v\D\zs\]\[\ze\D\]/*PPE+
```

It converts this:

```
[i][j]
[i+1][j]
[i][j+1]
[i+1][j+1]
```

To this:

```
[i*PPE+j]
[i+1][j]
[i][j+1]
[i+1][j+1]
```

...by matching `<not-a-digit>][<not-a-digit>]`, but setting only the `][` to be included in the match.

Notes:

- [`\D`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5CD) is easier to type than `[^0-9]`
- I'm matching a closing `]` rather than `<not-plus-or-minus>`

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a good answer. What I was looking for is the part with `\zs` and  `\ze`. Can you tell me what is wrong with my approach above? I'm looking to learn how to make this more scriptable and afair `\zs` and `\ze` only work if you have one submatch.

Comment: What your command is doing is replacing your match with the result of your `substitute()` call. After making the correction suggested by @Hotschke your substitute call boils down to `substitute("][", "*PPE+", "", "")`, which means "in the string `][` substitute `*PPE+` with the empty string. `*PPE+` does not appear in the string `][`, so this always returns `][`.

Comment: I think you probably want something more along the lines of `substitute(submatch(0), "][", "*PPE+")`, but I haven't tested that.

Comment: @TheKaltur No probs. Glad I could help!